# Rsync with ssh-keygen to ssh user with limited commands and specifc directory

Tags: ssh, rsync, ssh-keygen

I have two machines, local and remote.

I want to back up my files and folders to the remote machine automatically, using rsync to transfer files and folders, using ssh-keygen to automatically log into the remote machine.

I can do this as ssh root, but that will be a bit of security risk: someone can log directly into the remote machine as root if the local files have been compromised.

I tried rssh but I couldn’t log in automatically using ssh-keygen.

What I am looking for is a way to create an ssh user with limited access to shell commands and with access only to a specific directory safe for automatically logging in with no harm to the remote machine.

Comment: I'm not really sure this will work for you.  If you can rsync files over, it may be possible to rsync a replacement authorized_keys file that doesn't have that restriction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can limit the command run when using a ssh key-pair by using `command="...."` into `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file. Example took from [here](http://www.sakana.fr/blog/2008/05/07/securing-automated-rsync-over-ssh/):

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys 
command="/usr/local/bin/rsync --server -vlogDtprz --delete . /tmp",no-pty,no-agent-forwarding,no-port-forwarding ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1y[...] kattoo@spaghetti
```

Answer (score 5):

rsync includes a [rrsync](http://gitweb.samba.org/?p=rsync.git;a=blob;f=support/rrsync;hb=HEAD) example script that can restrict rsync.

Example:

```
command="/usr/local/bin/rrsync -ro /data",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa [...]
```

That way you don't have to hardcode the commandline from the client on the server.